# MediaElement doesn't display the pre-loaded video

Tags: c#, wpf

The pre-loaded video does show a preview in the "Design View" in VS-2019 but when I run the code, the video doesn't play the video at all.

The MediaElement is the background of my window and the video should start playing when I start the program.I've tried setting the video using code (not in the xml) and setting the behavior to Mannul among other things. The preview of the window does show the video but when I execute the code the video won't play and I'm left with a white screen.***the video and the code are in the same folder***

The video is a 1080p WMV file (plays just fine in the windows media player)

Comment: <MediaElement x:Name="background" Stretch="Fill" Source="Background.wmv" LoadedBehavior="Play" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1280" Height="720"/>

Comment: thats the code, I forgot to add it apparently